# Power Apps Canvas - import data from excel sheet

Tags: excel, canvas, powerapps

I'm developing an application by using Powerapps canvas. I have a problem while importing data from the excel sheet, the first issue that some of the rows not been displayed on the page, second on all dates and time are not displayed correctly especially time. the table name Arrival and there are two columns STA for both date&time-"custom data type" and Arrival Time - "Time data type". I think I have a problem with zone time. I tried (TimeValue, DateVale, and DateTimeValue) functions and all of them didn't work or maybe I'm using these functions wrong way. look at the pictures to understand my problem more
I need help guys

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us what you have done so far. What is your question in detail?

Comment: ok, I have a flight schedule in the excel sheet and I'm taking this information to the application. when I import the data from excel sheet every column displayed correctly unless ("STA"   column: for date and time), for example, first flight in the excel sheet Arrival Flight Arr ID From City              STA             Arrival Time   Arr Term
XY0057           D         RUH Riyadh  1/23/2020 1:00     1:00:00 AM        S

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Excel times need to be adjusted for time zone. You can do that using the following expression:

```
Text(
    DateAdd(ThisItem.Time; TimeZoneOffset(ThisItem.Time); Minutes);
    DateTimeFormat.ShortTime24)
```

The `DateAdd` expression will take the time from Excel and adjust it to your local time; the `Text` will then convert it into a text so that you can display on a label in your gallery.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for help, but when I used the commend shows me an error. my code is : Text(DateAdd(ThisItem.STA; TimeZoneOffset(ThisItem.STA); Minute); DateTimeFormat.ShortTime24)